# Related questions' scores break at 3 digits

Tags: bug, design

Since MSE posts frequently hit 100+, this seems to be a problem.

[image: bad css]

The "What is a disputed flag?" post has a score of 157.  The highest rated question here currently has a score of 1341, so in fixing this you should probably make it safe for at least 4 character scores.

Alternatively, you could show scores in base 64.

Comment: Possibly because you didn't search before you reported these bugs. :P